# MultiValueDictKeyError hen adding lines with inlineformset

Tags: django, inline-formset

I am trying to add more lines on the inline formset factory using the same methodology that I used before on a formset factory but is getting an error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError form-TOTAL_FORMS'
```

models.py:

```
    class ttransactions(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=tx_choices)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default='Description')
    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today, db_index=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class ttransaction_lines(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(ttransactions, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=debit_credit)
    ledger_account = models.ForeignKey(tledger_account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    vat_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    vat_code = models.ForeignKey(tvat, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

forms.py:

```
    class TransactionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    transaction_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=year_range), initial=datetime.today)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(TransactionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ttransactions
        fields = ['description',
                  'transaction_date']

class TransactionLinesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ttransaction_lines
        fields = ['transaction_type', 'ledger_account', 'amount']
   
class BaseTransactionLinesFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(BaseTransactionLinesFormSet, self).clean()
        # Check errors dictionary first, if there are any error, no point in validating further
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        balance = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data['DELETE'] == True or form.cleaned_data['DELETE'] == '':
                continue
            if form.cleaned_data['transaction_type']=='Debit':
                balance = balance + form.cleaned_data['amount']
            else:
                balance = balance - form.cleaned_data['amount']

        if balance != 0:
            message = 'Transactions not balanced (excluding deleting lines)'
            raise forms.ValidationError(message)
            
TransactionLineFormset = inlineformset_factory(ttransactions,
                                               ttransaction_lines,
                                               form=TransactionLinesForm,
                                               can_order=True, can_delete=True)
```

views.py

```
class JournalCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
template_name = 'accounting/journal.html'
model = ttransactions
formset = TransactionLineFormset
form_class = TransactionsForm

success_url = '/accounting/transaction_list'

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(JournalCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    formset = TransactionLineFormset(queryset=ttransaction_lines.objects.none())

    formset.form.base_fields['ledger_account'].queryset = \
        tledger_account.objects.filter(company=request.user.current_company)

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    extra_forms = 1
    if 'additems' in request.POST and request.POST['additems'] == 'true':
        formset_dictionary_copy = self.request.POST.copy()
        formset_dictionary_copy['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = \
            int(formset_dictionary_copy['form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + extra_forms
        formset = TransactionLineFormSet(formset_dictionary_copy)
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  formset=formset))

    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    formset = TransactionLineFormset(self.request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid()):
        return self.form_valid(form, formset)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, formset)

def form_valid(self, form, formset):
    form.instance.company = self.request.user.current_company
    self.object = form.save()

    sequence = 1
    for line in formset:
        line.instance.sequence = sequence
        sequence += 1

    formset.instance = self.object
    formset.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              formset=formset))
```

I get the error on the line that dictionary copy line. The code for adding the line is added in the post function. I am not sure if that is the correct place to add this code. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if the form submitted is missing the key.

The `.get()` method allows for a default when accessing a missing key in a dict.

```
formset_dictionary_copy['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = \ 
    int(formset_dictionary_copy.get('form-TOTAL_FORMS', 1)) + extra_forms
```

It appears that, the formset is not getting all it's hidden values or a different form is submitted.

I would consider a frontend solution or sending a single initial formset with the add button values.

A frontend / js example:
https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/django-dynamic-formsets-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed as recommended but is now getting this error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'. Please have a look again.

Comment: `form-TOTAL_FORMS` is a None value, what is getting submitted from the form. Is there a default value of 1?  Without changing too much code, you might simply try/except for the None case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I moved the additems code a few lines lower to after the formset = TransactionLineFormset(self.request.POST) and it finds form-TOTAL_forms now. Thanks again.